# Google AdMob for Android Studio, interstitial ads with a function to randomize presentation at a set frequency

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, ads

I want interstitial ads to show randomly when I click a button. For example, I want to choose between 1-20. That the ad pops up randomly and not at every click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float hitPercent = 0.3f; //30% of the time it will show ad
final Random generator = new Random();

myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (generator.nextFloat() <= hitPercent) {
            ad.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! So glad you got it!